# Playwright waitForResponse how to wait till the response has text "completed"

Tags: angular, typescript, automated-tests, protractor, playwright

I Have a scenario where the API receives multiple responses(one at a time) and renders on the UI.
API keeps on polling the DB till it is done with receiving all the responses.
I need my script to wait till the API response becomes "completed". I tried below code but it is not waiting till the status is completed.

```
const response = await page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes('https://services/url') && response.status() === 200);

console.log('RESPONSE ' + (await response.body()));
```

Below is the logged response

```
{
  "transactionDetail": {
    "transactionID":"866f357f-7541-4ff2-b879-61ca284513a7",
    "transactionTimestamp":"2021-08-02T10:48:50.372207",
    "inLanguage":"en-US",
    "serviceVersion":"1"
  },
  "resultSummary":{
    "inputCount":1,
    "successCount":1,
    "failureCount":0},
    "inquiryDetail": {
      "kaseIterationId":"8a7b11547af8835d017b067ad06e04ba"
    },
  },
  "response":"InProgress"
}
```

How can i make my script wait till the "response" becomes "Completed" instead of "Inprogress".

Comment: The `waitForResponse` method takes `boolean | Promise<boolean>` as possible condition. Just return a promise after looking into the body (using `response.json()`)

Comment: Can you please give an example.

Comment: Just try passing a promise to the function... you can do it ;)

Comment: @Prasad When the response will be completed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by supplying an async predicate to `page.waitForResponse` like this:

```js
async function isFinished(response) {
    return response.url().includes('https://services/url') && response.status() === 200 && (await response.json()).response === 'Completed'
}

const response = await page.waitForResponse(async (response) => await isFinished(response));
```

Comment: How can i achieve the same using playwright with java.

Comment: @Prasad that sounds like a separate question.